# Does Weaver's Ultimate Work if you're under Axe's Berserker's call

Tags: dota-2

I was playing matchmaking on Dota 2 last night and I picked Weaver. Sometimes in team fights I got a bit too close to Axe and i got caught by his Berserker's call and eventually died. All the while I kept pressing my Ultimate Hotkey, but Time Lapse didn't work.

At first I thought, maybe I didn't have enough mana and that I failed to notice it, but the same thing happened even after level 16 when Time Lapse is 0 mana. And all this while my teammates kept saying that I was failing with my Ultimate.

So My question is, does Weaver's ultimate work under Axe's Berserker's call?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When affected by Axe's Beserker's Call, you are forced to attack Axe, so you will be unable to use Weaver's Time Lapse or any other active abilities you have. The mechanics of this skill work similarly to the 'taunt' mechanic in Warcraft III, which was the inspiration for this skill.

If Axe happens to die/can't be attacked while Berserker's Call is active, enemies will instead be frozen in place until it ends.

See [here](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Axe) for more information on Axe's skills.

Comment: So, that makes LC's Duel just a bad Beserker's Call?

Comment: @ResidentBiscuit Considering the two skills are used completely differently and function completely differently, I don't see how you can compare them.

Comment: @ResidentBiscuit Actually LC's Duel is a better Berserker's Call...If someone is under Call from Axe and LC starts duel then they will duel LC not attack axe.